# Appcelerator Titanium - how to view alert in logcat?

Tags: appcelerator, logcat

If i have an alert in my app

`alert("howdy");`

What do i have to do to view that alert using the adb logcat command? I've tried `adb logcat *:v` but nothing shows up - even though I can see the alert in the running app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert()` shows a dialog in Android, doesn't do any console/adb.

However, if you want things to show up you should use logging tools

If you dive into [documentation](https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.API) you need to use the `debug`, `info` and `error` methods to insert different levels of logging.

`console.log()`, `console.warn()` and `console.error()` work too.